# Geometric prime distribution

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-number-theorem, prime-constellations

Let integers $\ a>1\ $ and $\ b\in\mathbb Z\ $ be relatively prime (hence $\ b\ne 0).\ $ The Dirichlet's prime distribution theorems apply to the arithmetic sequence

$$ (_aG_b(x) : x\in\mathbb Z) $$
where
$$ _aG_b(x)\ :=\ a\cdot x + b\ $$

Thus, for arbitrary integer $\ s>0\ $ that is relatively prime to
$\ b,\ $ I'd like to see some prime distribution theorems for the nearly geometric sequence

$$ \left(\left(\bigcirc^n\,_aG_b\right)(s):
   \ s\in\mathbb Z_{_{\ge0}} \right) $$

where $\ \bigcirc^n\ $ is my notation for the composition power (*please, let be, do not "correct it"*).  Can you prove any? It must be difficult but one may try to prove **comparison** prime distribution theorems where one **compares** the distribution of primes of two nearly geometric sequences (even **without** knowing anything specific about any single sequence like this).

---

Let

$$\ \gamma\ :=\ \frac b{a-1} $$

Then
$$ _aG_b(x)\ =\ a\cdot(x+\gamma)-\gamma $$
and
$$ \forall_{n\in\mathbb Z_{_{\ge0}}}\quad
 \left(\bigcirc^n\,_aG_b\right)(s)\ =\ a^n\cdot(x+\gamma)-\gamma  $$

Thus, we may rewrite our nearly geometric series as

$$ \left(a^n\!\cdot\!(x+\gamma)\,-\,\gamma\,:
   \ \ n\in\mathbb Z_{_{\ge0}}\right) $$
(making it more *geometric*).

---

---

**Examples**:

- $\ \left(\bigcirc^n\,_2G_1\right)(1)\ $ -- the $n$-th Mersenne number;
- $\ \left(\left(\bigcirc^n\,_2G_1\right)(p):
     \ p\in\mathbb Z_{_{\ge0}} \right)\ $ -- a potential source for Sophie Germain primes (in particular when $\ p\ :=\ _2G_1(s)\ $ is prime, while natural number $\ s\ $ is not prime)

---

Of course, one would like to know as much as possible about subsequences of consecutive prime terms of nearly geometric sequences.

Comment: I'm fairly sure there is no sequence of this shape which is known to contains infinitely many primes.

Comment: @Wojowu, the key phrase is "no ... known".

Answer (score 1):

**Modest start**. Let integers $\ a>1\ $ and $\ b\in\mathbb Z\ $ be relatively prime (hence $\ b\ne 0),\ $ and let
$$ \gamma\ :=\ \frac b{a-1} $$

Let $\ p\in\mathbb P\ $ be a prime, $\ p\not\!|\,a-1,\ $
and let $\ 0<\gamma_p<p\ $ be such that

$$\ (a-1)\cdot\gamma_p \equiv b \mod p $$
(under proper terminology, you could say $\ \gamma_p\equiv \gamma\mod p.)$

Let $\ a\ $ be a primitive root of prime $\ p,\ $ i.e. let

$$ \{a^k: k=0\,...\,(p-2)\} $$
represent all $\ p-1\ $ non-zero residua $\mod p.$

The only (tiny) chance $ \mod p\quad $ for a nearly geometric long finite subsequence of consecutive terms $\ \left(\bigcirc^n\,_aG_b\right)(x)\ $ that are all prime is condition $\ x\equiv -\gamma_p\mod p.\ $ Then
$\ p\not\!|\left(\bigcirc^n\,_aG_b\right)(x)\equiv -\gamma_p\mod p.$

**Otherwise**, let
$$ x\not\equiv -\gamma_p\mod p\quad \Rightarrow $$

The above sign $\ \Rightarrow\ $ tells us and let us remember that the above statement is an assumption (*please, do not "correct" my notation*).

Then, $\ x+\gamma_p\not\equiv 0\mod p,\ $ hence ($a\ $ being a primitive root) there are natural numbers $\ n_p\ $ such that
$$ a^{n_p}\cdot(x+\gamma_p)\ \equiv\ \gamma_p\mod p $$
i.e
$$ p\ | \left(\bigcirc^{n_p}\,_aG_b\right)(x)
      \ \equiv a^{n_p}\cdot(x+\gamma_p)-\gamma_p \mod p   $$
We have obtained an entire infinite sequence of terms indexed by exponents
$\ n_p,\ $ and these terms are not primes, except possible the first one, because they are divisible by $\ p.$ The indices $\ n_p\ $ form an arithmetic series with the difference between the two consecutive of them
is $\ n_q-m_p=p-1.$

---

We may apply the above approach to more general modules besides the primes.

---

When the same $\ a\ $ is a primitive root for several primes (or similar)
then we may combine them, thus, significantly increase the non-prime terms
hence severely thinning out the set of *potential prime terms*.

(*All this opens a plethora of further questions, e.g. related to the primitive roots, etc.*)

Comment: I like the originality of your thinking, it reads really promising.